# C# Implementaion of New-Service cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, service, windows-services

I need to install an executable as service, and I need to do that from withing a PowerShell cdmlet written in C#. In essence I need to create the required registry entries etc. which will define the service (including the executable to run - a kind of srvany.exe).

I also need to be able to define the logon identity (credentials) of this service.

TIA, Hans

What have I tried so far. I have been looking at the ServiceProcessInstaller and ServiceProcessInstaller classes, but they miss the possibility of defining the 'external' executable.

```
    public partial class MyServiceInstaller : Installer
    {
        public MyServiceInstaller()
        {
            IDictionary saveState = null;
            this.Installers.Clear();
            ServiceProcessInstaller spi = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            ServiceInstaller si = new ServiceInstaller();
            spi.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            spi.Username = null;
            spi.Password = null;
            si.ServiceName = "MyService";
            si.DisplayName = "MyService";
            si.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
            si.Description = "MyService - I wish....";

            spi.Installers.Add(si);
            this.Installers.Add(spi);
            this.Install(saveState);
        }
    }
```

Got stuck here since I cannot find a way of adding the executable path (service imagepath)

Comment: And [`what have you tried`](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? What particular difficulties did you encounter with your code? All I can see in your question is `I need to ...`, but nowhere I saw `here's the code I tried but ...`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check the [FAQ] and [About] pages to see what sorts of questions are most welcome here.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have the following code working and I am just wondering is there a more 'native' way to do it.

```
                Command psc = new Command("New-Service");
                psc.Parameters.Add("Name", svcName);
                psc.Parameters.Add("BinaryPathName", svcExec);
                psc.Parameters.Add("DisplayName", svcName);
                psc.Parameters.Add("Description", svcDesc);
                psc.Parameters.Add("StartupType", "Automatic");
                WriteVerbose("Verifying service account");
                if (Account == null) { WriteVerbose("- Using LocalSystem account"); }
                else { psc.Parameters.Add("Credential", crd); }
                WriteVerbose("Installing service");
                Pipeline pipeline = Runspace.DefaultRunspace.CreateNestedPipeline();
                pipeline.Commands.Add(psc);
                Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Brad Bruce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5008/brad-bruce) I found what I needed in: [How do I install a C# Windows service without creating an installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193424/how-do-i-install-a-c-sharp-windows-service-without-creating-an-installer)

I made a small adjustment to the IntegratedServiceInstaller class, the call to "SINST.Install(state)" will produce 3 lines of output

```
Installing service 'ServiceName'...
Service 'ServiceName' has been successfully installed.
Creating EventLog source 'ServiceName' in log Application...
```

Similar lines are written to the console when calling SINST.Uninstall(null)

I suppress this output by redirecting the output to Stream.Null

```
    System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Stream.Null);
    System.IO.TextWriter tmp = Console.Out;
    Console.SetOut(sw);
    try { SINST.Install(state); }
    catch (Exception Ex) { Console.SetOut(tmp); Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message); }
    finally { Console.SetOut(tmp); }
```